Python: How to check if ANY object is selected
I'm relatively new to Python and still struggle with some logic. I've searched for an answer already, but the examples/solutions are mostly outdated or too complex for my understanding.
Can someone give me a quick up-to-date example of how to check if "any object is selected" and return a True or False then, or "do something" if True.
Something like this:
if any_object_selected():
  # do this
else:
  # do that


if you mean to check any object as being a camera or a light or a mesh object then you can use if bpy.context.selected_objects or if you want to make sure only 1 any object is selected then use if len(bpy.context.selected_objects) == 1 or do you mean any MESH object?

I mean ANY OBJECT. If ANY OBJECT is selected, do this, if not do that. Basically I would like to test "if nothing is selected" and execute some code then. Thank you.

If you want to check if any object of any type is selected you can do something as simple as:
import bpy

if bpy.context.selected_objects:
    print("any object is selected")
else:
    print("nothing is selected")

Take note that this will also print the first statement if more than one object is selected. If you want to ensure that any one object is selected you can use:
import bpy

if len(bpy.context.selected_objects) == 1:
    print("any object is selected")
elif bpy.context.selected_objects:
    print("more than one object is selected")
else:
    print("nothing is selected")


Thank you a lot!

The following also works:
import bpy

try:
    bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
    print("something selected")
except:
    print("nothing selected")


If someone want to save time you can also use this version:
import bpy

selected = bool(bpy.context.selected_objects)
# equals 'True' if any object selected, 'False' if not

Sybren Stüvel suggested this to me as the fastest solution.
